# How can I get React styleguidist to install correctly and get past the peer Dependency issues with react-simple-code-editor: React 16 & 17?

Tags: reactjs, npm, peer-dependencies, styleguidist, react-simple-code-editor

I am in the process of learning React by reading the [Fullstack React book](https://www.newline.co/fullstack-react/).

---

My setup:

```
node -v
v14.15.3
npm -v
7.3.0
```

---

Following the [styleguidist install guide](https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/getting-started/) I ran:

```
npm -i -D webpack react-styleguidist
```

This installed:

- webpack v5.11.0
- react-styleguidist 11.1.5

There appears to be some sort of conflict between:

- [react-styleguidist](https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist) and
- [react-simple-code-editor](https://github.com/satya164/react-simple-code-editor).

This appears to be down to a peer-dependency in the react-simple-code-editor on React 16 baseline, whereas react-styleguidist uses React 17.

**package.json** for *react-simple-code-editor*:

```
....
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^16.0.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.0.0"
}
```

I raised the issue [here](https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/issues/1736) but never heard back.

**So I wondered if anyone here on SO with more in depth knowledge of React 16 to 17 enhancements can answer whether the react/react-dom in the react-simple-code-editor can be relaxed to use 16+? If so what is the syntax?**

More info on Peer Dependencies [here](https://blog.domenic.me/peer-dependencies/).

Answer (score 1):

React Styleguidist has a [peer dependency of `"react": ">=16.8"`](https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/blob/97f7ad646f245bd51b64210ea9290de892f71565/package.json#L96). I'm assuming that prior to installing react-styleguidist, you ran `npm install --save-dev react`, and that would have installed react@17.x.

You have two choices:

1. Downgrade to React@16.x

   Look at the updates in the [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) or in the [summary blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html). If you don't see any must-have changes and are more concerned about the conflicts, downgrade to resolve the peer dependency issue.
2. Install the peer dependencies anyway

   `npm 7.x` has more strict error handling for peer dependency issues, and I was able to install these packages on `npm 6.x` in a React@17 app with no problem, but my colleague hit the same issue and was able to bypass it with `npm install --force`. Run that and it should work fine. I haven't had any issues yet and have been happily ignoring what is a mere warning on my npm version.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check later. One of the reasons I went with the latest was with the newer builds of everything, including npm itself you can audit the packages you have installed to make sure there are no security vulnerabilities. Not sure if this technique will undermine that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by npm 7's [exciting new feature](https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/#peer-dependencies) that automatically installs peer dependencies. This results in both React 16 and React 17 being installed which makes everything explode.

Fortunately you can opt out of the new functionality with:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

It's less exciting but on the plus side it works.